# Prolog - Recursive Function Abs / Create new list

Tags: prolog

I want a function that given a Point, and a List of points it calculates:
the absolute value of (Point - PointofList), for every point of the list. 
I have this code so far, but I seem to be failing on the recursive part.

```
absL((X,Y),[],Result) :- Result.

absL((X,Y),[(X2,Y2)|Z], R) :- ABSX is abs(X-X2),
 ABSY is abs(Y-Y2),
 append([(ABSX,ABSY)], NL, R),
 absL((X,Y),Z,NL).
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the base case wrong.
When there are no more points in the list of points, the resulting list should be an empty list, but you are just leaving an uninstantiated variable:

So, your base case should read:

```
absL((_,_),[],[]).
```

I left the first argument with a structure using unnamed variables because the coordinates for the given point are not needed for the base case.

Your recursive clause is a bit more complex than it should. You really don't need to use `append/3` to build the resulting list. You can build the list directly in the head of the clause:

```
absL((X,Y),[(X2,Y2)|Z], [(ABSX,ABSY)|NL]) :- 
  ABSX is abs(X-X2), 
  ABSY is abs(Y-Y2), 
  absL((X,Y),Z,NL).
```

The recursive step will add the new distance before the recursive call and just insert this values when unifying the third argument at return of the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

this clause `absL((X,Y),[],Result) :- Result.` attempt to **call** Result, at least in Prologs that accept such syntax.

since @gusbro already shows the required correction, I'll show an alternative:

```
absL((X,Y), L_In, L_Out) :-
   maplist(absPoint((X,Y), L_In, L_Out).

absPoint((X, Y), (X2,Y2), (ABSX, ABSY)) :-
   ABSX is abs(X-X2), 
   ABSY is abs(Y-Y2).
```